# most efficient way to check if a string contains specific characters

Tags: java, string, validation

I have a string that should contain only specific characters: `{}()[]`

I've created a validate method that checks if the string contains forbidden characters (by forbidden characters I mean everything that is not `{}()[]` )

Here is my code:

```
private void validate(String string) {

    char [] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    for (Character c : charArray) {
        if (!"{}()[]".contains(c.toString())){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The string contains forbidden characters");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there are better ways to do it since my approach doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko What did you test to use it?  I tested it and it was working as expected for me.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I've tested it with multiple test cases and for me is working. Maybe I've missed something

Comment: @Cristian Iacob This post may be better suited for the code review stackexchange since it seems to be working code that you want optimized/reviewed.

Comment: I would create String outside for loop which contains "{}()[]"

Comment: You can also use **Regex**. Something like this ```[{}()[]]```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I took the way you implement this, I would personally modify it like below:

```
private static void validate(String str) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if ("{}()[]".indexOf(c) < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The string contains forbidden characters");
        }
    }
}
```

The changes are as follows:

- Not declaring a temporary variable for the `char` array.
- Using  `indexOf` to find a character instead of converting `c` to `String` to use `.contains()`.
- Looping on the primitive `char` since you no longer need
  `toString()`.
- Not naming the parameter `string` as this can cause confusion and is not good practice.

**Note:**  `contains` calls `indexOf()`, so this does also technically save you a method call each iteration.

Comment: If you created a `Set` out of `{}()[]` signs it would be O(n) solution as for now it is O(n * m) in worst case.

Comment: @michalk I was more going the route of reviewing _his_ solution, rather than coming up with a completely different one.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Stream if you are using Java 8.
This allow you omit char to String boxing stuff.

```
private void validate_stream(String str) {
        if(str.chars().anyMatch(a -> a==125||a==123||a==93||a==91||a==41||a==40))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The string contains forbidden characters");
}
```

The numbers are [ASCII codes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for forbidden characters, you can replace them with chars if you want:

```
(a -> a=='{'||a=='}'||a=='['||a==']'||a=='('||a==')')
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works for you: I have added my code along with your code.

I have used a regex pattern, where `\\` escapes brackets, which has special meaning in regex. And use matches method of string, it try to matches the given string value with given reg ex pattern. In this case as we used not(!), if we give string like `"{}()[]as"`, it satisfies the if not condition and prints "not matched", otherwise if we give string like `"{}()[]"`, else case will will print. You can change this how you like by throwing exception.

```java
private static void validate(String string)
{

    String pattern = "\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]";
    if(!string.matches(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("not matched:"+string);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("data matched:"+string);
    }
    char [] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    for (Character c : charArray) {
        if (!"{}()[]".contains(c.toString())){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The string contains forbidden characters");
        }
    }
}
```

All the brackets are Meta characters, referenced here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/index.html